# PersistentTabView coming up when keyboard is shown for showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `showModalBottomSheet` that comes up that prompts the user to input text.

When the keyboard is shown, the `showModalBottomSheet` does move up, but so does the `PersistentTabView`.

I have tried wrapping the child of the `showModalBottomSheet` with a `Scaffold` and setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true`, which did work... but causes the sheet to extend the whole screen.

I am using the `persistent_bottom_nav_bar` package.

Bottom navigation bar:

```
MaterialApp(
   home: PersistentTabView(
      context,
      controller: _controller,
      screens: _screens,
      onItemSelected: (index) {},
      items: [
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          title: "Home",
          onSelectedTabPressWhenNoScreensPushed: () {},
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
            "assets/icons/Discover.svg",
            semanticsLabel: 'Discover',
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          activeColorPrimary: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          iconSize: 30,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          title: "Search",
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
            "assets/icons/Search.svg",
            semanticsLabel: 'Search',
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          activeColorPrimary: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          iconSize: 30,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          title: "Library",
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
            "assets/icons/Heart.svg",
            semanticsLabel: 'Library',
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          activeColorPrimary: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          iconSize: 30,
        ),
      ],
      confineInSafeArea: false,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF121212), // Default is Colors.white.
      handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, // Default is true.
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // This needs to be true if you want to move up the screen when keyboard appears. Default is true.
      stateManagement: true, // Default is true.
      hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true, // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument. Default is true.
      popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
      popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
      itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties(
        // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
      navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style12, // Choose the nav bar style with this property.
    );
);
```

ModalBottomSheet: (basically a textfield and a button)

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      ),
      builder: (context) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15)),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15)),
              child: Column(
                [INPUT TEXT WIDGET AND BUTTON]
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it this way, using the root navigator:

```
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    useRootNavigator: true,
```